# Alignement of a set of equations to the left. Only numbering one

Tags: numbering, align

I have the following code which produces what is shown in the picture below.

```
\begin{equation}\label{df20}
\begin{aligned}
u = u_0 + \Delta u, \hspace{20pt}  p = p_0 + \Delta p, \hspace{20pt} \Phi = 
\Phi_0 + \Delta \Phi \\
v = v_0 + \Delta v, \hspace{20pt}  q = q_0 + \Delta q, \hspace{20pt} \Theta = \Theta _0 + \Delta  \Theta \\
w = w_0 + \Delta w, \hspace{20pt}  r = r_0 + \Delta r, \hspace{20pt} \Psi = 
\Psi_0 + \Delta \Psi \\
X = X_0 + \Delta X, \hspace{20pt}  Y = Y_0 + \Delta Y, \hspace{20pt} Z = Z_0 + \Delta Z \\
L = L_0 + \Delta L, \hspace{20pt}  M = M_0 + \Delta M, \hspace{20pt} N = N_0 + \Delta N 
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
```

[image]

I would like to have the equations aligned at the left (maybe not totally to the left but each line should start at the same level.
Moreover I wanted them numbered as a block (as it is shown), so I can not use fleqn. I could use \notag but I dont like that solution because when the number of lines is even it wont be in the middle.

I know there are tons of questions about this, and trust me, I have been looking for a long time, but I didnt find anything that fulfil my requirements.

Comment: Start each line within `aligned` with `&`.  (But I’d rather recommend aligning at the `=` signs…)

Comment: I cant believe it was so easy! I have tried a lot! Thanks!

Comment: also put two `&&` just before the second and third small equations in each line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`aligned` allows any number of column pairs; there's no need for explicit spacing.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{df20}
\begin{aligned}
u &= u_0 + \Delta u, & p &= p_0 + \Delta p, & \Phi   &= \Phi_0 + \Delta \Phi \\
v &= v_0 + \Delta v, & q &= q_0 + \Delta q, & \Theta &= \Theta _0 + \Delta  \Theta \\
w &= w_0 + \Delta w, & r &= r_0 + \Delta r, & \Psi   &= \Psi_0 + \Delta \Psi \\
X &= X_0 + \Delta X, & Y &= Y_0 + \Delta Y, & Z      &= Z_0 + \Delta Z \\
L &= L_0 + \Delta L, & M &= M_0 + \Delta M, & N      &= N_0 + \Delta N 
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You also can use `alignedat` to have control on the spacing of the columns of equations, and the environment `fleqn` from `nccmath` to align a groups of equations on the left. The distance from the left margin is an optional argument (0pt by default).

Here are two possible layouts:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, nccmath}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{fleqn}[2em]
\begin{equation}\label{df20}
\begin{alignedat}{3}
 & u = u_0 + \Delta u, & \qquad & p = p_0 + \Delta p, & \qquad & \Phi = \Phi_0 + \Delta \Phi \\
 & v = v_0 + \Delta v, & & q = q_0 + \Delta q, & & \Theta = \Theta _0 + \Delta \Theta \\
 & w = w_0 + \Delta w, & & r = r_0 + \Delta r, & & \Psi = \Psi_0 + \Delta \Psi \\
 & X = X_0 + \Delta X, & & Y = Y_0 + \Delta Y, & & Z = Z_0 + \Delta Z \\
 & L = L_0 + \Delta L, & & M = M_0 + \Delta M, & & N = N_0 + \Delta N
\end{alignedat}
\end{equation}
\end{fleqn}
\vspace{1em}

\begin{fleqn}[2em]
\begin{equation}\label{df20}
\begin{alignedat}{3}
  u &= u_0 + \Delta u, & \qquad p &= p_0 + \Delta p, & \qquad \Phi &= \Phi_0 + \Delta \Phi \\
  v &= v_0 + \Delta v, & q& = q_0 + \Delta q, & \Theta & = \Theta_0 + \Delta \Theta \\
  w &= w_0 + \Delta w, & r & = r_0 + \Delta r, & \Psi& = \Psi_0 + \Delta \Psi \\
  X &= X_0 + \Delta X, & Y & = Y_0 + \Delta Y, & Z &= Z_0 + \Delta Z \\
  L &= L_0 + \Delta L, & M & = M_0 + \Delta M, & N &= N_0 + \Delta N
\end{alignedat}
\end{equation}
\end{fleqn}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Also an array seems suitable for this case:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{*3{ r@{{}={}}l }}\label{df20}
u & u_0 + \Delta u, & p & p_0 + \Delta p, & \Phi   & \Phi_0 + \Delta \Phi       \\
v & v_0 + \Delta v, & q & q_0 + \Delta q, & \Theta & \Theta _0 + \Delta  \Theta \\
w & w_0 + \Delta w, & r & r_0 + \Delta r, & \Psi   & \Psi_0 + \Delta \Psi       \\
X & X_0 + \Delta X, & Y & Y_0 + \Delta Y, & Z      & Z_0 + \Delta Z             \\
L & L_0 + \Delta L, & M & M_0 + \Delta M, & N      & N_0 + \Delta N 
\end{array}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

> [image]